# Problem with lightning input pattern

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, html

How do I ensure that the user only types numbers in lightning: input?

Currently tried with pattern but to no avail:

```
<lightning:input type="text" label="Numeric value" aura:id="myInput" name="myInput" pattern="[0-9]"/>
```

[image]

Also, I would like to format this field to a decimal with one place after the comma.

For that I already used the "step = 0.1" but also to no avail.

Comment: why are you not using a number type component as mentioned bellow by sfdcfox?

Answer (score 1):

Use the "number" type instead:

```
<lightning:input type="number" step="0.1" ... />
```

The "text" type is not suitable for your purpose.

Comment: i need use "input" instead of "lightning input"?

Comment: @DiegoEdargoPessoa whoops m no, that was a typo. I'll edit.